# Unable to show Menu item by clicking on the icon using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to framework, I wanted to show menu item when we click on the icon, I couldn't able to figure it out where I'm going wrong.

here is the code:

```
 <div>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="more"
          aria-controls="simple-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          <AccountBalanceIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu"
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={Boolean(this.state.anchorEl)}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
```

Can anyone help me in getting a popup while I click on the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IconButton` does not have a `value`, so you're setting state to `undefined`. You just want the `target` anyway, since its the element itself that will serve as the anchor, not the value.

Change your handler to this:

```js
handleClick = event => {
  this.setState({ anchorEl: event.target });
};
```

**Also:** Please provide all the relevant code the the question itself. The event handlers are the most important part of the problem and they are only located off-site.

Comment: Thanks!, I was thinking there might be a problem in jsx code. Thanks for letting me know about this :).